# MIPS - Store integers into an output_file

Tags: file, integer, output, mips, store

I am looking for a way to store integers into an output file. I googled it for quite a while but I was unable to find something.

I have 5 integers stored in $t3 - $t7 and I'd like to put those integers into a .txt data, how does it work?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your target execution environment. Are you using a simulator (which one), or are you running the program on some actual MIPS-based hardware (if so, which OS are you running on it)?

Comment: Im running the program on a kbuntu 14(Linux) with QtSpim (Spim MIPS Simulator)

Comment: Ok, so you convert your integers to strings, and then look up [the appropriate system calls](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) for opening and writing to files.

Comment: Isn't there a way to store numbers into a file? Because I have no clue how to turn an integer to a string (My first time doing MIPS)

Comment: Not that I know of. Questions on how to convert integers to strings have been asked many times before. Do a google search for "mips integer to string".